# Unable to deserialize the response

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I have searched and found this thread :
[Microsoft.Bot ConnectorClient SendMessage Unable to deserialize the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609327/microsoft-bot-connectorclient-sendmessage-unable-to-deserialize-the-response)
But there is no code and explanation.

So far I have this :

```
  var obj = model[i];
                    var userAccount = new ChannelAccount(obj.toId, obj.toName);
                    var botAccount = new ChannelAccount(obj.fromId, obj.fromName);
                    var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(obj.serviceUrl));

                    IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.conversationId) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.channelId))
                    {
                        message.ChannelId = obj.channelId;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        obj.conversationId = (await connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(botAccount, userAccount)).Id;
                    }

                    if (botAccount.Name == "")
                        botAccount.Name = "Bot";
                    if (userAccount.Name == "")
                        userAccount.Name = "User";



                    message.From = botAccount;
                    message.Recipient = userAccount;
                    message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: obj.conversationId);
                    message.Text = "Hello, this is a notification";
                    message.Locale = "en-Us";
                    await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);
```

My message object :

> {Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ChannelAccount}
>       Id: "49gjgijl7a4inc821c"
>       Name: "Bot"
>
> message.Recipient
>       {Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ChannelAccount}
>           Id: "default-user"
>           Name: "User"
>
> message.Conversation  {Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationAccount}
>       Id: "a0m69i29gih3kjf3mc"
>       IsGroup: null
>       Name: null
>
> message.Text = "Hello, this is a notification";
>                       message.Locale = "en-Us";

I'm getting this error when trying to post :

> Unable to deserialize the response.

e.InnerException

> {"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '',
>   line 0, position 0."}
>       Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
>       HResult: -2146233088
>       HelpLink: null
>       InnerException: null
>       LineNumber: 0
>       LinePosition: 0
>       Message: "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0."
>       Path: ""
>       Source: "Newtonsoft.Json"
>       StackTrace: "   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader
>   reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader,
>   Type objectType)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Rest.Serialization.SafeJsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String
>   json, JsonSerializerSettings settings)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.d__6.MoveNext()"
>       TargetSite: {Boolean ParseValue()}

Any help ?

Edit :  This is how I deserialize object.

```
  HttpContent requestContent = Request.Content;
            string jsonContent = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            List<ConversationModel> model = new List<ConversationModel>();


            try { 
            model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ConversationModel>>(jsonContent);
```

This is my object content :

```
 channelId: "emulator"
    conversationId: "a0m69i29gih3kjf3mc"
    email: "some-email@hotmail.com"
    fromId: "49gjgijl7a4inc821c"
    fromName: ""
    serviceUrl: "http://localhost:3979"
    toId: "default-user"
    toName: ""
```

I am adding to name and from name explicitly for local testing (see the code).

Comment: Can you provide the text that is being deserializaed?

Comment: Yes. I edited my post and added my object content.

Comment: Whats the statuscode of the request (any error?) and what is actually in the `jsonContent`-variable (I presume some html/xml response)?

Comment: Everything is okey in the response. The problem occurs when posting async ....

Comment: Can you post the value of jsonContent; exactly as inspected in Visual Studio.

Comment: That's jsonContent, at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Btw,  trying to "initialize" conversation with multiple users. Users are stored in my database.

Comment: I solved this issue. I was getting properties from context after authenticating the user. So i didn't send parameters in the url i need. 
Now, i'm getting properties before the user redirect for authentication, and setting properties in a static class.
Case closed !

Answer (score 1):

Here you have `IsGroup` and `Name` properties which are set to null:

> message.Conversation {Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationAccount} Id:
>   "a0m69i29gih3kjf3mc" IsGroup: null Name: null

Try giving values to those properties.

Also mistake could happen here too :

```
if (botAccount.Name == "")
  botAccount.Name = "Bot";
if (userAccount.Name == "")
  userAccount.Name = "User";
```

Checking emptiness of strings with `string == ""` will fail in case of `null` objects (when `botAccount.Name = null` or `userAccount.Name = null`).
Try using `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` instead:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(botAccount.Name))
  botAccount.Name = "Bot";
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userAccount.Name))
  userAccount.Name = "User";
```

Comment: Is group propertiy is set to null when info about the channel is saved as null. Also Name.
When response is parsed is equal to "".
So that is not problem .... Another idea maybe ?